# Maven project Importing issue

Tags: maven, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to import one Maven project into my Eclipse. But while importing , each and every time i am getting error pop up.

Could anyone please help me in this regards?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lGJsT.png)

Comment: does it build on plain command line? My assumption is using http instead of https to central https://blog.sonatype.com/central-repository-moving-to-https

Comment: No. I just simply tried to import one existing Maven project. during import only, i got that error message.

Comment: @Smriti Follow khmarbaise advice. Try to build it on command line. See the error. Look for connection problems, either because you still use http instead of https or because you are behind a proxy/firewall.